# Photogallery / slider not rendering dots according to number of slides

Tags: javascript, typescript

Was wondering if anyone can spot the error in the code here. Basically want the amount of dots to correspond to the amount of slides being rendered on the page. Dont mind the console logs, was just to see what the heck i was doing. /**DOTS CODE HERE**/ is where the code is that may be problematic

Markup is here (from an Elixir file) and JS below-

```
  def slider(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <div id={"#{@section_id}"} phx-hook="GallerySlider">
      <div class="wrapper relative w-full">
        <i id={"left-#{@section_id}"} class="fa-solid fa-angle-left" phx-update="ignore"></i>
    
        <div class="carousel flex flex-row">
          <%= render_slot(@images) %>
        </div>
        <i id={"right-#{@section_id}"} class="fa-solid fa-angle-right" phx-update="ignore"></i>
      </div>
      <ul id={"dots-#{@section_id}"} class="list-inline dots"></ul>
    </div>
    """
  end
end
```

JS

```
const GallerySlider = () => {
    console.log('this', this.el)
    const carousel = this.el?.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.carousel')!
    console.log('carousel', carousel)
    const firstImg = carousel.querySelector('div')!
    console.log('firstImg', firstImg)
    const arrowIcons = this.el?.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.wrapper i')
    console.log('arrowIcons', arrowIcons)
    const dots = this.el?.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.dots')
    console.log('dots', dots)
    const slideCount: number = carousel.children.length
    console.log('slideCount', slideCount)

    let isDragStart = false
    let isDragging = false
    let prevPageX: number
    let prevScrollLeft: number
    let positionDiff: number
    // calculate dots
    let scrollCount: number = 0
    let resolution = window.innerWidth
    let paginationOffset: number = resolution >= 0 && resolution <= 768 ? 3 : 4
    let pagination: any = slideCount - paginationOffset

    arrowIcons?.forEach((icon) =>
        icon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault
            const isLeft = icon.id.includes('left')
            const firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 32
            const scrollEnd = scrollCount + paginationOffset >= slideCount

            carousel.scrollLeft += isLeft ? -firstImgWidth : firstImgWidth

            // add/remove active states from dots
            if (!isLeft && !scrollEnd) {
                scrollCount += 1

                dots?.children[scrollCount - 1].classList.remove('active')
                dots?.children[scrollCount].classList.add('active')
            }

            if (isLeft && scrollCount > 0) {
                scrollCount -= 1

                dots?.children[scrollCount + 1].classList.remove('active')
                dots?.children[scrollCount].classList.add('active')
            }
        })
    )

    const autoSlide = () => {
        const position =
            carousel.scrollLeft - (carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth) > -1

        if (position || carousel.scrollLeft <= 0) return

        positionDiff = Math.abs(positionDiff)
        const firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 16
        const valDifference = firstImgWidth - positionDiff

        const positionValue =
            positionDiff > firstImgWidth / 4 ? valDifference : -positionDiff
        carousel.scrollLeft +=
            carousel.scrollLeft > prevScrollLeft ? positionValue : -positionValue
    }

    //Dragger
    const dragStart = (e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {
        isDragStart = true
        prevPageX = 'pageX' in e ? e.pageX : e.touches[0].pageX
        prevScrollLeft = carousel.scrollLeft
    }

    const dragging = (e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): void => {
        if (!isDragStart) return
        e.preventDefault()
        isDragging = true
        carousel.classList.add('dragging')
        positionDiff =
            'pageX' in e
                ? (e.pageX as number) - prevPageX
                : e.touches[0].pageX - prevPageX
        carousel.scrollLeft = prevScrollLeft - positionDiff

        // add/remove active states from dots
        let isLeft = carousel.scrollLeft < positionDiff
        let scrollEnd = scrollCount + paginationOffset >= slideCount
        console.log('isLeft', isLeft)
        console.log('paginationOffset', paginationOffset)
        console.log('scrollCount', scrollCount)

        if (!isLeft && !scrollEnd) {
            scrollCount += 1
            console.log('scrollCount', scrollCount)

            dots?.children[scrollCount - 1].classList.remove('active')
            dots?.children[scrollCount].classList.add('active')
        }

        if (isLeft && scrollCount > 0) {
            scrollCount -= 1

            dots?.children[scrollCount + 1].classList.remove('active')
            dots?.children[scrollCount].classList.add('active')
        }
    }

    const dragStop = (): void => {
        isDragStart = false
        carousel.classList.remove('dragging')

        if (!isDragging) return
        isDragging = false
        autoSlide()
    }

    /*********/
    /**DOTS CODE HERE**/

    for (let i = 0; i <= pagination; ++i) {
        const dot = dots?.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))!

        if (i === 0) dot.classList.add('active')

        console.log('dot thing', i)
        dot.classList.add('list-inline-item')
        dot.classList.add(i.toString())
        dot.innerHTML = i.toString()
        console.log(i, 'added')
    }

    // window.onresize = (_event) => { };
    /*********/

    carousel.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart)
    carousel.addEventListener('touchstart', dragStart)

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragging)
    carousel.addEventListener('touchmove', dragging)

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop)
    carousel.addEventListener('touchend', dragStop)
}

export default GallerySlider
```